# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]:

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

hive is launched correctly under ubuntu.

[image]

But when trying to insert values to  tables  in beeline the following error appears:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException
>   [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values File
>   /tmp/hive-atef/atef/21019ad4-eee4-43a8-8487-47e4a59054b4/_tmp_space.db/Values__Tmp__Table__1/data_file
>   could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). 
>   There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this
>   operation.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change permissions to temporary hdfs directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125999/how-to-change-permissions-to-temporary-hdfs-directory)

Comment: Please don't repost the same problem