# how to change permissions to temporary hdfs directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I use hive2.1.0. with sql when I want to insert a value into a table, the following error will appear:

[image]

i tried to modify the file / tmp permission in order to allow the temporary files of HDFS to have all the rights 777. but after a new connection to the beeline a new file will be created with the rights rwx - x - x: as it is shown here:

[image]

Comment: Use access control lists (ACL) with inherited privileges for new files & sub-dirs. That's the only way to work around HDFS default `umask` and explicit app-level privs settings.

Comment: The problem is not permissions... `There are 0 datanodes running` is the real error here